# ¿por que no puedo multiplicar ni dividir en un ciclo while en c#?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una practica en la cual tengo que elevar un numero a x potencia con while. Pero no logro que el codigo multiplique, probe sumar y restar con el mismo codigo y funciona pero no lo hace con multiplicacion o divicion.

Este es el codigo

```
        int p = 0, n = 0, r = 0, cont = 1;
        string valor = "";
       
        Console.WriteLine("dame el numero");
        valor = Console.ReadLine();
        n = Convert.ToInt32(valor);

        Console.WriteLine("dame la potencia");
        valor = Console.ReadLine();
        p = Convert.ToInt32(valor);

        while (cont <= p)
        { 
            r = r * n;
        cont++;

        }
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", r);
```

Comment: Intenta usando `Int32.Parse(valor)` en lugar de `Convert.ToInt32(valor)`. Saludos.

Comment: Para el caso de multiplicar o dividir, no puedes inicializar R a 0, puesto que la asignación de `r = r / n` o `r = r*n` te va a dar siempre 0...

Comment: gracias por tu sugerencia. probe con Int32.Parse pero me sigue dando resultado 0.

Comment: muchas gracias Jakala tenias razon estaba iniciando r con 0. al iniciarla con 1 si funciono.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La solución es que estás inicializando `r` a 0. Esto hace que al hacer el while estés multiplicando por 0 y siempre es 0.

Para ello:

```c
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    int p = 0, n = 0, r = 1, cont = 1;
        string valor = "";
       
        Console.WriteLine("dame el numero");
        valor = Console.ReadLine();
        n =  Convert.ToInt32(valor);

        Console.WriteLine("dame la potencia");
        valor = Console.ReadLine();
        p = Convert.ToInt32(valor);

        while (cont <= p)
        { 
          r = r * n;
            cont++;
        }
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", r);
  }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias esa es la solucion estaba mal iniciada r = 0. gracias por tomarse el tiempo en ayudar.

Comment: Si te ha ayudado colabora dando a la ✔ de la izquierda de la respuesta. Un placer ayudar.